# Output an array using recursion

Tags: c++

I am trying to output a simple array using recursion and here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int first7(int *aptr, int n) {
    if(n == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    first7(aptr+1,n-1);
    cout<<*aptr;
    return 0;


}
int main(){
    int arr[50],n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    first7(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

I wished to output it starting from 0th index. but it turned out to be opposite.

1.please tell me what is wrong with my code?

2.what should i do to display it starting from the 0th index and so on

3.if i remove the `return 0` statement after the `cout` statement, then also it works fine. How is it?

Comment: Print *before* you recurse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the item before you recurse:

```
void first7(int *aptr, int n)
{
  if(n == 0)
  {
    return;
  }

  cout << *aptr;
  first7(aptr+1, n-1);
}
```

Note that there's also no need to return a value, so I've removed that.

If you want to output the array in reverse order then just do the recursion before the printing:

```
void first7(int *aptr, int n)
{
  if(n == 0)
  {
    return;
  }

   first7(aptr+1, n-1);
   cout << *aptr;
}
```

You've asked about the `return` statement in the comments. You only need a `return` statement to exit before the end of the function. When the functions gets to the last line it will automatically return without you having to do anything about it. If you're unsure about this then just run the code through a debugger and see what happens.

Comment: Why didn't you write anything after `return ` keyword? I am getting an error when I don't write anything after `return` keyword.

Comment: @varunsharma - because I've changed the return type to `void` so there doesn't need to be anything after the `return` keyword.

Comment: so if i want to output the array in reverse order, i would have to flip the `cout << *aptr;` with the ` first7(aptr+1, n-1)` statment. Right? So how will the control go back to the previous elements, after the last element is displayed, without a `return` statement?

Comment: can you please help?